# The sum of squared loadings in PCA summing to 1

Tags: pca

In PCA, we essentially create a new factor with the original variables in a linear combination manner such that:
$Y_1 = a_{11} \times x_1 + a_{12} \times x_2 + a_{1p} \times x_p$.

The sum of **squared** loadings of all variables (features) for each PC sum to 1. Therefore, is it **safe** to say that factor $i$ contributes the squared loading amount to the PC $j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this presentation](ftp://statgen.ncsu.edu/pub/thorne/molevoclass/AtchleyOct19.pdf):

> **Factor loadings (factor or component coefficients) :** The
>   factor loadings, also called component loadings in PCA, are the
>   correlation coefficients between the variables (rows) and
>   factors (columns).
>   Analogous to Pearson's r, *the squared factor loading is the
>   percent of variance in that variable explained by the factor*.
>   To get the percent of variance in all the variables accounted
>   for by each factor, add the sum of the squared factor
>   loadings for that factor (column) and divide by the number of
>   variables. (Note the number of variables equals the sum of
>   their variances as the variance of a standardized variable is
>   1.) This is the same as dividing the factor's eigenvalue by the
>   number of variables.
>
> **Eigenvalue:** Column sum of squared loadings for a factor, i.e., the latent root. It conceptually represents that amount of variance accounted for by a factor.  The ratio of eigenvalues is the ratio of explanatory importance of
>   the factors with respect to the variables. If a factor has a low
>   eigenvalue, then it is contributing little to the explanation of
>   variances in the variables and may be ignored as redundant with more
>   important factors. Eigenvalues measure the amount of variation in the total sample accounted for by each factor. A factor's eigenvalue may be computed as the sum of its squaredfactor loadings for all the variables.